# Switch laptop disk drive without reinstalling Linux?

Tags: system-installation, hard-disk, replace, cloning

I have Lubuntu 17.04 installed on my laptop's HDD. I've now bought an SSD, of almost the same size, as a replacement; it's empty, untouched.

Now, I want to switch the disks and have basically the exact same contents that I already have on HDD moved to the SSD - and have my Linux boot up and run without needing any further adjustment (except perhaps `/etc/fstab` UUID issues).

How can I do this...

1. Without the help of an extra PC?
2. With the help of an extra PC?

Notes:

- I can generate bootable USB sticks if necessary.
- I have access to a CD/DVD reader if necessary.
- The HDD is at 33% usage, so the data will fit - but the HDD capacity is slightly larger.
- The HDD may have some sectors which are borderline bad (but for now - Linux boots and works).
- There's only one partition on the HDD, and from what I've heard - I can keep it that way on the SSD as well considering I'm the sole user, and it's not used as some public server etc.

Comment: Since I guess this is a duplicate, only a comment, but: if you have an external hard drive, you can use clonezilla to create an image of your HDD, and then unpack that image to your SSD. If you're able to connect both SSD and HDD at the same time, you don't even need an external hard drive and can simply mirror the HDD's contents (clonezilla will again help).

Comment: @Zeta: Is this possible even when the partition size (not the used size, the capacity) on the HDD is larger than the one on the SSD?

Comment: There are many ways to replicate, even doing tar on one disk and untaring on the destination.

Comment: @einpoklum [Yes](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disks). Without clonezilla it's even easier. Please keep a live USB system ready, since you likely have wrong UUIDs in either `/etc/fstab` or your GRUB config. But to be honest, I'd reinstall Lubuntu on the SSD and then `rsync` my home and maybe some additional configuration files

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Can you write an answer which either lists several ways or recommends one in particular? Recall that tar'ing and untar'ing into a filesystem does not make the drive bootable; I need a complete solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two basic ways to switch your install to a new disk, clone the disk or copy the contents and fix the system (ie bootloader, fstab entries). Both methods have their benefits and disadvantages.

Both methods require another system with this disk attached and either some extra storage or the second disk. This can be another laptop or desktop - or live usb/cd on the actual laptop.

It is easiest if you can attach both disks to the system - but if you cannot do that you can use the extra storage as a temporary staging area while you swap the drives. A large usb hard disk drive can be used if you have one. A easier option might be to get a [usb enclosure](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sata-Hard-Drive-Caddy-Enclosure/dp/B003MVVPZI) instead which will allow you to attach both disks to the same computer.

So using a live usb and a usb enclosure you can do the entire thing from the laptop you want to replace the drive in. For both the methods I will discuss doing a direct disk transfer with both disks attached and that neither of them are mounted (ie you have boothed another computer or are working on a live usb/cd). I will use `/dev/sdS` to indicate the source disk (the hdd in your case) and `/dev/sdD` to indicate the destination disk. Replace these with the actual disks on your system - be sure to verify these disks as getting it wrong will destroy any data you have the destination.

### Method 1: Cloning the disk

This is the simplest method when going from a disk to one of the same size or larger, but with an extra step can go from a larger disk to a smaller one. The main disadvantage of this is it copies the disk block by block and so requires reading and writing the whole disk. This will take longer then copying the system when the disk is mostly empty.

You mentioned going from a slightly larger to a smaller disk, so the first step is to resize the partition on the source disk to a size smaller than the destination disk. This is easiest to do with [gparted](https://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux), just ensure you shrink the drive so the free space is at the end of the disk. This can take a while as it will have to move any data at the end of the disk to a new location.

Now you simply clone the source disk to the destination with `dd` or `ddrescue`. `ddrescue` might be advisable as it tries harder to reread bad sectors which you mentioned you might have.

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sdS --force /dev/sdD
```

or alternatively with `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdS of=/dev/sdD
```

Note that you will get an error that the destination disk was full during writing - this is fine as the end of the disk should not contain anything useful since we resized the disk. This is why you must ensure you resize it to a size slightly smaller than the destination.

Now you can use gparted again to resize the destination to fill the drive.

You should now be able to swap the disks and boot the new system.

### Method 2: Copying the root filesystem

This method can be quicker if you are only using a small amount of space on a large disk but requires more steps to reconfigure the bootloader and fstab in order to boot the system. It also has the advantage of being read only on the source disk so less is less likely to break your original disk (although this is only not true for the above method as you have to resize the disk due to the destination being smaller than the source). It is also more flexible as you can easily change the partitions however you want.

The first step is to set up the partition table on the new drive and format the partitions. You mentioned you only have one partition on the drive - from this I assume you are using legacy bios booting (as uefi requires a vfat partition in addition to the root filesystem). This is easiest to do with `parted`:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdD mklabel msdos
sudo parted /dev/sdD mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdD1
```

but you can also use `fdisk` or `gdisk` or even `gparted` if you prefer. If your source disk has more partitions or you want to change the partition layout you can do so now - just setup the destination disk however you want or require.

Now mount the source and destination disks.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/src /mnt/dest
sudo mount /dev/sdS1 /mnt/src
sudo mount /dev/sdD1 /mnt/dest
```

If you have/want more partition than this mount the root at the above location and the other partitions relative to that. (for example if you source had a extra boot partition mount it to /mnt/src/boot).

Now copy the contents form the source to the destination.

```
sudo rsync -avh /mnt/src/ /mnt/dest/
```

This will take a while. If it gets interrupted you can resume it by rerunning the command.

You can now unmount the source drive as we no longer require it.

```
sudo umount /mnt/source
```

The final steps are to fix the system so it can boot. First open `/mnt/dest/fstab` and fix it for the new system - if the partition layout is the same this should be a matter of updating the UUID/drive number to reflect the new partition. Use `blkid` to get the required information, it is recommended to use `UUID=` or `PARTUUID=` if available.

Lastly we need to fix the bootloader - here I assume you were using grub2 with a legacy bios, if this is not true disregard this and follow instructions for how to restore your bootloader.

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/dest/boot /dev/sdD
```

More information on restoring the ubuntu bootloader can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#BIOS.2FMBR_Notes).

If all goes well you should be able to shutdown, swap the drives and boot the new disk.

### Extras

#### Working via a third disk

If you cannot attach both disks to one computer you will require some extra storage - this could be a usb disk, network attached storage or anything else you can access locally and is large enough to store disk or root filesystem.

The overall process is the same in both methods above, but rather then copying from one disk to another you copy to a the tempoary staging area first;

With Method 1:

Note that this requires the staging area to be as large as the disk you are copying.

With the storage mounted to `/mnt/staging`:

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sdS /mnt/staging/rootfs.img
```

You can all the file whatever you want. From here you could compress it and keep it as a backup of your system if you wish.

Then you can shutdown swap the drives and boot the live usb again to restore the image

```
sudo ddrescue /mnt/staging/rootfs.img --force /dev/sdD
```

Note that the drive numbers for the source and destination might be the same with this method.

With Method 2:

Note that this only requires the staging area to be as big as the filesystem when compressed rather than the whole disk.

With the storage mounted to `/mnt/staging` and the source mounted to `/mnt/src`:

```
sudo tar -C /mnt/src -caf /mnt/staging/roofs.tar.gz /
```

Then you can shutdown swap the drives and boot the live usb again to restore the filesystem after setting up the destination disks filesystem.

```
sudo tar -C /mnt/dest -xf /mnt/staging/roofs.tar.gz /
```

Then continue to restore fstab and the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (if the HDD is smaller than the SDD and the SDD could be connected to the computer) is to:

1. boot to a pen-drive distro. This avoids having temporal files opened in your HDD.
2. Copy with dd the whole disk HDD to the SDD:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/HDD of=/dev/SDD bs=4k
   ```

   Of course HDD and SDD must be replaced with the correct names for the whole disks like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdd` (not partitions `/dev/sda1`).
3. Replace the HDD by the SDD in the computer.
4. Boot as always.

The only problem is that the UUID of both hardware will be identical and may prevent you from mounting the HDD partitions as an additional drive. That could be corrected later, if needed.

Comment: I did say the HDD is slightly larger than the SSD. Edited to make that clearer.

Comment: Then shrink the `/` partition with [gparted](https://gparted.org/) enought so it will fit inside the SDD (you may shrink the partition to 40% if the used space is only 33%). Understand that this is the risky part as your data is going to be modified by the shrink.

Comment: If you are resizing a disk resize it to just under the size of the destination disk rather than to the size of the root filesystem - gparted will need to move less data that way and will be a lot faster.